# Confused about how to prove a function is surjective/injective?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

Prove $f(x) = x^3$ is surjective. I've read about how to do these proofs online but I don't really understand it.

Obviously, the formula $y^{1/3} = x$ always maps to some x for any y, but I don't understand how to officially prove it. Someone said to let $y^{1/3} = x$ and $f(x) = x^3$ so $f(x) = y$.

I don't understand how that does anything. You're just taking the function of the inverse of the function which of course cancels out and results in $y = f(x)$

Comment: Are you allowed to use the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: For each $y,$ you want an $x$ so that $f(x)=y.$ So, for $y$ taking $x=y^{1/3}$ ensures $f(x)=y.$ Thus for each $y$ its pre-image is $y^{1/3}.$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I don't think that's what they want

Comment: @Goldname Then please provide more context. It's in your best interest.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos They want to prove it in the method I wrote, but I don't understand the proof.

Comment: The proof is simple:  Surjective means for every $y \in \mathbb R$ there is an $x\in \mathbb R$ so that $f(x) = y$.  Let $x = y^{\frac 13}$.  Then it follows that $f(x) = x^3 = (y^{\frac 13})^3 = y$.  We can find such an $x$ for every $y$.  So $f$ is surjective.  That is *all* there is to it.

Comment: @fleablood Ok then assume $f(x) = x^2$. $x = y^{1/2}$ and $f(x) = (y^{1/2})^2 = y$. What's wrong here then?

Comment: Take a function that is *not* surjective.  Let $g(x) = x^2$.  To prove it is surjective we have to prove that for all $y$ we can find and $x$ so that $x^2 = y$.  So ... can we.  If we say $x = \sqrt y$ that won't work if $y < 0$.  If $y = -5$ we need $x^2 = -5$ there is no such value so there is no $x$ so that $g(x) = -5$ so $g$ is not surjective.

Comment: "What's wrong here then?"  Well, if $y < 0$ then $x =y^{\frac 12}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @fleablood I see... so our original proof basically depends on our previous knowledge that x exists for $x = y^{1/3}$? But in that case, what's the point in the last step? Can't we just stop here?

Comment: @fleablood Can't everything be shortened to this one line: "all y can be mapped back to x because there is x for  $x = y^1/3$ for all y" But in this case, it's no different than just saying "this is surjective because it fits the definition."

Comment: " just taking the function of the inverse of the function which of course cancels out"  Not all functions have inverses.  And not all functions map to all values.  I think you are confused because it is so obvious that $f(x) = x^3$ does *both* that you don't get that proof is simply to prove that $f(x) = x^3$ does map to all values.  That is *all* you have to show.  And as all values *do* have an inverse, that is all you have to show.  It *IS* that simple

Comment: "Can't we just stop here? "  Um,  where?  What "last step".  Goal: prove that for all $y$ there is an $x$ so that $x^3 = y$.  Solution: Let $x = y^{\frac 13}$.  Then $x^3 = y$.  What is this "last step" or "here" that is confusing you?

Comment: @fleablood The last step is, the inverse function maps to all values of x. In other words, we just say "$x = y^{1/3}$ and since x is all real numbers, qed"

Comment: "Can't everything be shortened to this one line: "all y can be mapped back to x because there is x for x=y1/3 for all y""   Uh.... I don't understand why don't think that that is precisely what the proof said.

Comment: And.... what don't you understand about that?

Comment: @fleablood The proof just seems overly complicated to me. And the last part being $(y^{1/3})^3 = y$ is just redundant. I don't understand why that's required for the proof.

Comment: Welll.... you have to actually *state* that for every $a$ there is a $b$ so that $b^3 = a$.  You can say let $b = \sqrt[3]{a}$ and be done with it but for clarity sake, and for the student who doesn't quite see why this would imply the answer, stating "and therefore $f(b) = (\sqrt[3]{3}^3) = a$ and we are done" is a courtesy.  Without it a novice student is likely to no understand what the significance of $b = \sqrt[3]b$ is.  And the signifance of it *IS* that $b^3 = a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to do the mathematician wiggle and say this depends an what you have been taught so far and can take as a given.

If you have been told by God on high that for every $x \in \mathbb R$ then there $\sqrt[3]{x}$ exists then your proof will go like this:

$f(x) =x^3$ is surjective if for any $a \in \mathbb R$ there is exists $b \in \mathbb R$ so that $f(b) = a$.  Let $b = \sqrt[3]{a}$ then $f(b) = f(\sqrt[3]{a}) = (\sqrt[3]{a})^3 = a$.  So for every $a$ we *can* find a $b$ (namely the cube root of $a$) so that $f(b) = a$.  So $f$ is surjective.

However you might not be allowed to use that God told you every number has a cube root.  And you might need to prove it.

Were you taught the intermediate value theorem?  Can you take it for granted that $f(x) = x^3$ is continuous?

If $a > 1$ then $a^3 > a$.  ANd $1^3= 1 < a$.  So $f(1) < a < f(a)$.  That means there must be some $b: 1 < b < a$ so that $f(b) = a$.

And if $a = 1$ then $f(1) = 1^3 = 0 =a$.  And if $0< a < 1$ then $f(0) = 0 < a^3 < 1=f(1)$ so there is a $b: 0< b< 1$ so that $f(b) =a$ and ... so on.

But you would have to prove the Intermediate value theorem the first time you see it.

And we'd have to prove $f(x) = x^3$ is continuous.

Should I go on.

Comment: What if I turn your third paragraph into "$f(x) =x^3$ is surjective because for all a, there is a b such that $b = \sqrt[3]{a}$ "

Comment: It seems to me like we simply write down the fact that $f(b) = f(\sqrt[3]{a}) = (\sqrt[3]{a})^3 = a$ just to avoid repeating the exact definition of surjective.

Comment: If we stopped at "there is $b = \sqrt[3]{a}$", then how do we know $b^3 = a$? We haven't actually *stated* that. Now admittedly it's obvious and an experienced mathematician can turn to another and say "Let $b =\sqrt[3]{a}$ be the value we need" and that'd be the end of it.  But pity the novice student, being now to the definition and the concept of proof and not really follow.  "We say let $b = \sqrt[3]{a}$; we're done".  Um, what? Why?  Then we say "Well, then don't you see $b^3 =  \sqrt[3]{a}^3 =a$ so for every $a$ there is a $b$ so that $f(b) = a$".  Hopefully the respons is.  "Oh, yeah!".

Answer (score 1):

A function $f:U\longrightarrow V$ always has $3$ ingredients.
$U$ is the function's *domain*, $V$ its *codomain*, and $f$ is the relation that associates to each element $u \in U$ some element $v=f(u)\in V$.

---

Now, a function need not attain all the values in $V$.
For instance, take $f:\mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=x^2$.
If $v<0$, then there is no $u\in\mathbb R$ with $f(u)=v$.
The set of values of $V$ that are attained by $f$ is called the *image* $\text{Im}(f)$ of $f$.
In our previous example, we had $\text{Im}(f)=[0,+\infty)$.
Indeed, every nonnegative real number $v$ has a real square root $u=\sqrt a$, which satisfies $f(u)=v$.

When $V=\text{Im}(f)$, we say $f$ is *surjective*.
Hence, while $f:\mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is not surjective, $f: \mathbb R\longrightarrow [0,+\infty)$ is.

---

The association $v=f(u)$ in general need not be unique.
This means that, given $v\in \text{Im}(f)$, there might be more than one $u\in U$ with $f(u)=v$.
For instance, take our previous example. Given any positive real number $v$, we have that both $u_1=\sqrt v$ and $u_2=-\sqrt v$ are solutions to $f(u)=v$.

When this does **not** occur -- that is, when the association is unique --, we say that $f$ is *injective*.
Hence, while $f:\mathbb R \longrightarrow [0,+\infty)$ is not injective, $f: [0,+\infty) \longrightarrow [0,+\infty)$ is.

---

When a function is both surjective and injective, we say it is *bijective*.
In this case, we may define an inverse function $g=f^{-1}:V\longrightarrow U$ which associates to each $v\in V=\text{Im}(f)$ the unique $u\in U$ that solves $f(u)=v$.

---

To prove that some map is bijective, you hence need to know not only the map's domain (where it's defined), but **also** its codomain.
We've seen that even when the association is the same -- $f(x)=x^2$ in our examples --, changing the domain and codomain impact whether or not the function is surjective/injective.

Answer (score 0):

Given $y$, you are actually defining the $x$ that you are searching for as $y^{1/3}$ (note that $t^{1/3}$ is well-defined for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$). Then you plug it in to obtain $f(x)=x^3=\left(y^{1/3}\right)^3=y$.

Comment: that's the part I don't understand. How does this prove anything?

Comment: It proves that, for every $y$ you can find an $x$ such that $x^3=y$ - which is what you need for surjectivity. You have proven it by not just *finding* the $x$ but by giving a *formula* for $x$. Given $y$, that is, $x=\sqrt[3]{y}$ does the job, because $x^3=(\sqrt[3]{y})^3=y$.

Comment: but how do I know $y^{1/3}$ evaluates to a real value of x?

Comment: @Goldname Every real number $y$ has a cube root. We now *define* $x$ to be $\sqrt[3]{y}$. For $x$ *defined in such manner*, $f(x)=x^3=y$. And, you can do that for every $y\in\mathbb R$ that you started with.

Comment: It depends on your class and context.  In analysis classes you need to prove that for any $c > 0$ and any natural number $n$ there will exist a unique $b>0$ so that $b^n = c$.  We call that number $c^{\frac 1n}$. If follows that if $c > 0$ then $c^{\frac 13}$ exists and that $(-c^{\frac 13})^3 = - c$ so cube roots exist for all reals.  It's clear from context proving all reals have odd power roots is to be assumed as a given.

Answer (score 0):

If a function has an inverse that is defined on the whole real line then the function is a bijection, hence injective (one to one) and surjective (onto).

Here we can define $g(x) = (\operatorname{sgn} x) \sqrt[3]{|x|}$ and
check that $f(g(x)) = x$. Hence for any $y$, we know that there is
some $x$ ($=g(y)$) such that $f(x) = y$.